# C# reversing order of a Concurrent Stack

Tags: c#, concurrency, stack

I would like to reverse the order of a concurrent stack in a thread safe and performance efficient way. The way I'm thinking of doing this is to pop each element of the concurrent stack and push it into another temporary concurrent stack. Once finished, the temporary stack will contain the reversed order and the main stack will be empty. I was then going to do something like this:

```
mainStack.PushRange(tempStack.Reverse().ToArray());
```

However, I don't think this would be thread safe.

TIA

Comment: Well, if you're going to lock around it when using it to do this, you need to use that same lock around it wherever else it's used, or else it can still be modified when doing this.  If you do that, you've pretty much defeated the point of using a ConcurrentStack.

Comment: Ya.  Just use a lock with a LinkedList<T> and a bool to tell you which end to feed off of.

Comment: If you are planning to reverse a stack reasonably often, rather than very rarely, you should ideally use a different underlying structure than what C# uses.  You probably want to use a data structure that can efficiently add/remove to both ends.  A Deque would be best, but a circular array could work.  Then you can just have a boolean indicating whether it's forward or backward and just flip it to reverse everything.  Obviously the whole stack would need to be written yourself so that all access methods could choose which end to act on.

Comment: @Servy Just out of curiosity is there a name for this type of data structure?

Comment: @Kevin I named two different types of data structures.  To my knowledge there is no name for a stack that flips which end it reads/writes to; there may well be one.

Comment: @servy Sorry for the confusion, what you say makes sense but it appears the lock is not for the concurrent stack but for something for another variable that is sometimes used with the stack. I've now amended my original question as the stack isn't always used within a lock block.

Comment: @millie That's much worse.  That means that someone else can add/remove items from the stack while you're part way through your reversal process.  That's **very bad**.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I needed this much flexibility with a data structure (and was worried about the efficiency or functionality of data structures that currently exist in the framework), I would just write my own and include the necessary accessors and behavior modifying properties that I needed.  That way, you always know where to go if it isn't performing to expectations.